# "The controlmode control form has not been set" on Display Form

Tags: rating

I created a Display Form on a Custom List that have a rating column, but when I open this form with a user that is a non administrator, this error is show:

"The controlmode control form has not been set"

Someone can help me?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `SPContext.GetContext(this.Context).FormContext.FormMode = SPControlMode.Display;` inside `CreateChildControls(){ }`?

Comment: I created my Form on SharePoint Designer, I have no code behind to edit.

Another idea?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<PageFieldAverageRatingFieldControl:AverageRatingFieldControl FieldName="5a14d1ab-1513-48c7-97b3-657a5ba6c742" runat="server" ControlMode="Edit">
                                    </PageFieldAverageRatingFieldControl:AverageRatingFieldControl>
```